# Creating a `ggplot2` plot with distinct length scales for different x axis segments

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a ggplot2 plot with multiple `geom_rect` objects. For now, I'm trying to create a plot with two `geom_rect` objects. I need segments of the x axis to be one of two "scales". For example, the physical length between 0 and ten on the x axis might be 1 inch, while that between 10 and 20 is 0.1 inch.

The actual physical lengths (1 inch or 0.1 inch) for the intervals doesn't matter, but I need to keep their ratios the same. So, 10:1 for the "0 to 10 distance" vs. "the 10 to 20 distance".

Each `geom_rect` object would occupy exactly one of the x axis segments. That is, the first `geom_rect` object would span (on the x axis) the interval 0 to 10, the second would span 10 to 20.

So far, I've tried to use the ggplot2 function `scale_x_continuous` with a custom transform that I've defined via `trans_new` from the `scales` package.

```
boundary <- 10
mt2 <- scales::trans_new(
        name = "my",
        transform = function(position){
            y <- numeric(length(position))
            print(paste0("position: ", position))
            print(paste0("boundary: ", boundary))
            y[position <= boundary] <- position[position <= boundary]
            y[position > boundary] <- boundary + (position[position > boundary] - boundary) / 10
            print(paste("Transformed values:", y))  # Add this line for debugging
            return(y)
        },
        inverse = function(y){
            print(paste("Inverse input values:", y))  # Add this line for debugging
            print(paste0("boundary: ", boundary))
            z <- numeric(length(y))
            z[y <= boundary] <- y[y <= boundary]
            z[y > boundary] <- boundary + (y[y > boundary] - boundary) * 10
            print(paste("Inverse output values:", z))  # Add this line for debugging
            return(z)
        },
        domain = c(0, 20)
    )
```

```
gt <- tibble::tibble(start = c(0, 10), stop = c(10, 20))
p <- gt |>
    ggplot2::ggplot() + ggplot2::geom_rect(ggplot2::aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, ymin = -1, ymax = 1))
p + ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(trans = mt2)
```

When I run my code, I see this output:

```
[1] "position: 0"
[1] "boundary: 10"
[1] "Transformed values: 0"
[1] "position: 10"
[1] "boundary: 10"
[1] "Transformed values: 10"
[1] "Inverse input values: NA" "Inverse input values: NA"
[1] "boundary: 10"
Error in z[y <= boundary] <- y[y <= boundary] : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

It seems that when `scale_x_continuous` calls the inverse of the transform `mt2`, the inverse function gets as input a vector of two `NA`s.

Do you have suggestions on how I might fix this? And why is the inverse getting the input `c(NA, NA)`?

Comment: You should check out package `ggbreak`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/vignettes/ggbreak.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are making this much harder than it needs to be. Your trans object could just be:

```r
mt2 <- scales::trans_new("my_trans",
  transform = function(x) ifelse(x > 10, (x - 10) / 10 + 10, x),
  inverse   = function(y) ifelse(y > 10, (y - 10) * 10 + 10, y),
  domain    = c(0, 20)
)
```

Testing, we have

```r
library(ggplot2)

tibble::tibble(start = c(0, 10), stop = c(10, 20), fill = c('A', 'B')) |>
  ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, ymin = -1, ymax = 1, fill = fill)) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = mt2)
```

[image]

If you plan to do this thing quite often and change the threshold and compression factor, you could define a function that creates a trans object for you to call directly within `scale_x_continuous`

```r
trans_vary <- function(threshold, factor, domain) {
  scales::trans_new("my_trans",
    transform = function(x) {
      ifelse(x > threshold, (x - threshold) / factor + threshold, x)
      },
    inverse   = function(y) {
      ifelse(y > threshold, (y - threshold) * factor + threshold, y)
      },
    domain    = domain
  )
}
```

Which allows, for example

```r
tibble(start = c(0, 10), stop = c(10, 20), fill = c('A', 'B')) |>
  ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = stop, ymin = -1, ymax = 1, fill = fill)) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = trans_vary(threshold = 5, factor = 5, domain = c(0, 20)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Allan, I did upvote this as it provides a simple and elegant solution for the problem with 2 geom_rects, but something that I couldn't figure out easily is that how we can scale this if we had more than 2. Let's say another rectangle from 20 to 30 and we want these scaled with a factor of 2 and threshold of 10. Do you have a suggestion for that? (Probably we'd be using `floor( x / factor)` or something like that, but as I said, I couldn't figure it out). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If preprocessing of the data works for you, we can create new starts and stops that would follow your "transformed scale", and then plot those.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

## data
gt <- tibble::tibble(start = c(0, 10, 20, 30), 
                     stop = c(10, 20, 30, 40), 
                     reg = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4)))

## scaling factor for your axis
myscale <- 2   # in your case it'd be 10; I chose 2 to better illustrate
boundary <- 10  # width of your rectangles

## creating new starts and stops with the new scale
gt %>% 
  mutate(start_new = c(0, cumsum(boundary/myscale^(seq_len(n()-1) - 1))), 
         stop_new = cumsum(boundary/myscale^(seq_len(n()) - 1))) -> gt_new

## plotting with the new starts and stops
## x-axis labels are based on original values
gt_new %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start_new, xmax = stop_new, 
                         ymin = -1, ymax = 1, 
                         fill = reg)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(c(gt_new$start_new,gt_new$stop_new)), 
                     labels = unique(c(gt_new$start,gt_new$stop)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>